# div has a table in it does not scroll

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a table contained in a div. 
table layout is fixed. 
div has css property "overflow:scroll". 
but when I change div's with less than table's width,
scroll bar did not appear

Answer (score 1):

specify certain `width`, `height` to DIV and then `overflow:auto;`

```
overflow:auto;
width:500px;
height:400px;
```

check this code

```
<style type="text/css">   
  .pqr{
    overflow:auto;
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
   }
</style>
<div class="pqr">
  <table width="600px" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
    Test
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Salil.
I have tried "overflow:auto", it did not work, both in FF and IE :C
I will post my code leter.

Comment: Yes! it works.But my table's width is set on <col> 
<style type="text/css"> .pqr{ overflow:auto; width:500px; height:400px; } </style> <div class="pqr"> <table border="1"> <col width="600px" <tr> <td> Test </td> </tr> </table> </div>

Comment: sorry,I'm new here. I dont know how to post code like yours.
sorry for my bad english too :D

Comment: what is col? why you need that? just USE <table border="1" width="600px" >

Comment: @Salil Is there a way to do it with `width: 100%` for the scrollable div i.e. making the div fill its parent container?